# ErrorException Undefined variable $name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm getting this error when clicking a button on my dashboard

And this error only happens in the customization part, in other sections everything works fine

It gives me the solution below but I don't know how to apply

**$name is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $name }} with {{ $name ?? '' }}**

`Undefined variable $name (View: /home/dir/mysite.com/resources/views/admin/settings/personalization.blade.php)`

```
@push('styles_top')

@endpush

@section('content')
    <section class="section">
        <div class="section-header">
            <h1>{{ trans('admin/main.personalization') }} {{ trans('admin/main.settings') }}</h1>
            <div class="section-header-breadcrumb">
                <div class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="/admin/">{{ trans('admin/main.dashboard') }}</a></div>
                <div class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="/admin/settings">{{ trans('admin/main.settings') }}</a></div>
                <div class="breadcrumb-item ">{{ trans('admin/main.personalization') }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

                            @php
                                $items = ['page_background','home_sections','home_hero','home_hero2','home_video_or_image_box',
                                            'panel_sidebar','find_instructors','reward_program','become_instructor_section',
                                            'theme_colors', 'theme_fonts', 'forums_section', 'navbar_button','cookie_settings','mobile_app',
                                            'others_personalization'
                                         ]
                            @endphp

                            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab3" role="tablist">
                                @foreach($items as $item)
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link {{ ($item == $name) ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/admin/settings/personalization/{{ $item }}">{{ trans('admin/main.'.$item) }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>

                            <div class="tab-content">
                                @include('admin.settings.personalization.'.$name,['itemValue' => (!empty($values)) ? $values : ''])
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection

@push('scripts_bottom')


@endpush
```

I've tried several solutions suggested in other posts, but none worked.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

IN:
/home/dir/mysite.com/resources/views/admin/settings/personalization.blade.php)

error: You have not any variable $name.

**Solution:**
check that into **controller**, you are sending variable with view file?

**return view('file_path')->with("name", $valueVariable);**
return view("file_path".["name" => $valueVariable]);